# How can I change the CSS display property when clicking on a link/button?

Tags: javascript, css, display

I have a ul with the id of "menu-list". I have set the display property to "none" in my CSS file, but I would like it to change to "flex" when clicking on a link.

I am using the click event on the link to trigger the change of the display property, but nothing happens when I click on it.

When logging the value of the display property to the console inside myFunction(), I just get a blank log in the console, with no value displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
let menuList = document.getElementById("menu-list");

function myFunction() {
  console.log(menuList.style.display);

  if (menuList.style.display === "none") {
    menuList.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    menuList.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#menu-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <nav id='menu'>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="src/assets/images/hp-logos_white.png" alt="logo" class="fluid">
      </div>
      <ul id="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here:

You use an anchor instead of a button and as such it will redirect you to a new site.

Then the answer explains why your toggle is not working. However, the modern solution is to simply toggle a CSS class:

```js
const menuList = document.getElementById("menu-list");
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  menuList.classList.toggle('d-flex')
})
```

```css
[id="menu-list"] {
  display: none;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <nav id='menu'>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="src/assets/images/hp-logos_white.png" alt="logo" class="fluid">
      </div>
      <ul id="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button>
        Click to toggle
      </button>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of your comparison since initially no inline style is set on the element.

```js
let menuList = document.getElementById("menu-list");
function myFunction() {
  if (menuList.style.display === "flex") {
    menuList.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    menuList.style.display = "flex";
  }
}
```

```css
#menu-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <nav id='menu'>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="src/assets/images/hp-logos_white.png" alt="logo" class="fluid">
      </div>
      <ul id="menu-list">
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars">Click</i>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a ternary conditional operator would be more appropriate. Pros would solve it by toggling a CSS class instead.